# Swift over Objective C to use AVFoundation framework to scan barcodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, performance

I have a project that was developed in objective c. It includes Zbar library to scan barcodes. Im planning to replace Zbar library with build in AVFoundation framework. Now my doubt is, should i write the code to scan the barcode in objective c or swift? Writing the code in swift will increase the performance on barcode scan?

Comment: Performance is going to be the same - choose the language you're the most proficient with.

Comment: I don't think that you will increase the performance of the Barcodescanner with swift excessive. Choose the language which you prefer. If you are familar with objective c, I would prefer this because the rest of the project is also written in objective c. But you can also use swift, there is nothing against using it.

Comment: whichever fits better for you. opinion-based question. voted for close.